# Facing issue with drupal 7 auto generate URL alias

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

The auto generate url alias works when i click on Save configuration (which we get from this link "Configure URL alias patterns"). But next time when i flush the cache it is not working.

my pattern is content/[node:title]

but when i flush cache (class registry or page and else) it give me node/id

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with one of my Drupal site and i had followed the the following steps that resolved my issue:

```
1. Clear you Drupal cache.
2. Delete all existing aliases using bulk delete option.
3. Update or check the pattern settings and save the configurations.
4. Now generate the new URL aliases for all using the bulk update option.
5. And its done.
```

It worked for me to resolve my issue, hope will work for you.

Comment: thanx anurag.
 But when next time i am flushing cache same problem occurs ie no auto 
url alias generate . it gives me node/id